# How can I merge results into a single JSON while querying data from two different models in node.js and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two `mongoose` models in my app:

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    facebook_username: {type: String},
    display_name: {type: String}
}
```

and

```
var CommentsSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: {type: String, required: true},
    text_content: {type: String},
    photo_content_url: {type: String}
    comment_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
}
```

currently each single `comment` contains `user_id` - a direct link to its author.

I created a `node.js` endpoint that takes `POST` query and returns JSON with all details about comments:

```
commentsRoutes.post('/comments', function (req, res) {

    var startDate = req.body.startDate;
    var endDate = req.body.endDate;

    var query= {};
    query.$and = [];

    // and condition on start date
    if(startDate != undefined) {
        var startDate = new Date(req.param('startDate'));
        var endDate = new Date(req.param('endDate'));
        query.$and.push({"comment_date":{$gte: startDate}});
        query.$and.push({"comment_date":{$lte: endDate}});
    }

    var finalquery = Comments.find(query)
    finalquery.exec(function(err, comments){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(comments);
    });
});
```

This endpoint returns me a JSON with all the comments, however - I need to attach to each JSON details about its author - username, facebook_username and display_name (fetched based on `user_id` from `UsersSchema`). Can you tell me how could I do it?

`user_id` in `CommentsSchema` is a `mongoose id` of a specific user from `UsersSchema`

**====== EDIT**

Like @Antonio suggested in his answer below, I used `populate` in my case, it worked well and I saw merged JSON at the end. All user details were added, it looked like:

```
{ 
  "text_content": "blah",
  "photo_content_url": "http://www...",
  "comment_date": "some date",
  "created_at": "some date",
  "user_id": { "username": "someUsername",
               "facebook_username": "fbUsername",
               "display_name": "sth" }
}
```

however - is there a way to include `POST` parameters in my endpoint that will apply to the `user_id` json?

Currently I'm sending a `POST` parameters `startDate` and `endDate`. But if I send also `facebook_username` - how can I include it in a query and find only comments that were written by this author?

I tried adding a simple condition:

```
var fb_username = req.body.facebookUsername;
query.$and.push({"facebook_username": fb_username});
```

but it didn't work because there's no such field `facebook_username` in `CommentsSchema`...

So how can I include condition attached to fields from UsersSchema that will limit results from CommentsSchema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a reference to the corresponding user you could use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Taking into account that try this:

```
Comments
.find({ 
    comment_date: { 
        $gte: startDate, 
        $lte: endDate 
    }
})
.populate('user_id')
.exec(function(err, comments) {
    if(err) {
        return res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(comments);
});
```

By the way, not related to the main question, but since you are not doing any change in the server I think a GET would be a better option.

I also abbreviated your query, `$and` is not necessary here.

**EDIT**

You can add filtering to populate, in your case:

```
.populate({
  path: 'user_id',
  match: { 
    facebook_username: fb_username 
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you very much, I had no idea about `populate`! However, even when I'm using it - I'm still having some issues with the final query. I edited my original question - could you please take a look?

Comment: I took a look to the edit.

Populate just replace the reference (in your case `user_id`) with the corresponding document from another collection.

You are trying to add `facebook_username` as a query parameter to the collection `comments`, but since that collection does not have that field of course it is not possible.

In your case you should do a separate query.

Comment: Antonio, could you show me some example of how could I do the 2nd query and include the results within same json that comes from first query?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I just checked the docs again and it's possible to do a filtering with populate. I edited my answer including the new part.

Give a try!

Comment: Antonio, thanks for your help and most of all - patience! :) You answered my initial question clearly so I accepted your answer. I also posted additional question with a slightly different use case, could you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212600/how-can-i-rewrite-my-mongoose-query-after-splitting-data-from-one-model-into-two ? maybe you will know the answer for that... :) Thanks!